# Need explanation: vba find method troubleshooting

Tags: vba, find

I am using Find method to bring the cell value from another workbook.
The code below brings the value. But I wanted to erase Activate methods, so just using Block Statements with Find method to bring values from another workbook.
'Windows(wb_name).Activate

```
'Sheets("SheetA").Select
'Set rg =Worksheets("SheetA").Range("C:C")
'With rg
'value1 = Cells.Find(What:="11693", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, 
 SearchFormat:=False).Value
'End With
```

For clarifying, what exactly I want; in values1 = Cells.Find ...I changed Cells to rg but it doesnt work. I want to know why? Also I see it unnecessary to use activate . I want to write a code where I will get rid of Activate another workbook. So, just by giving source wb and ws names and range to look for the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub FindInOtherSheet()
  Dim Value1 As String, rg As Range
  Set rg = Workbooks("W1.xlsx").Worksheets("SheetA").Range("C:C")
    With rg
        Value1 = .cells.Find(What:="11693", After:=.cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
         SearchFormat:=False).value
    End With
End Sub
```

It starts searching after the first cell of the range. `ActiveCell` does not have sense in a not activated sheet...

**Edited**:

As an example to clarify your question about the `Find` "problem" of not returning any error in case of no any match, I would state that this should be considered an advantage.

You can simple check if the function returned a range in this simple way (I will use the above code to exemplify):

```
Sub FindInOtherSheet()
  Dim Value1 As String, rg As Range, fndCell as Range
  Set rg = Workbooks("W1.xlsx").Worksheets("SheetA").Range("C:C")
    With rg
        set fndCell = .cells.Find(What:="11693", After:=.cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
         SearchFormat:=False)
         'check if Find returned a range:
         If not fndCell is Nothing Then 'if a match has been found
             Value1 = fndCell.value
         Else
             MsgBox "No match has been found...": Exit Sub
         End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked with workbook name added. Thanks. Now I am reading some articles about Find method. If you have a resource about it, that would be great if you dare to share here

Comment: @user16316847 Isn't if enough to study the Microsoft page clearly defining what the method does? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) you can find the necessary information, I think.

Comment: I need a resource where it has written in details when Find to use. Because Range.FInd method does not give an error when code is not written well. I remember the day I wrote you, I had another issue with range.find it took two days of me. I watched many resources, but  at the end I did it another way. So, if you have a delibarate explanation of find, I would be grateful to read it. Thanks ahead!

Comment: @user16316847 The fact that `Find` did not return an error when does not match anything is an advantage. I no not know such a 'resource', but it should be good to use the next way able to check if a return exists. In fact, I will edit the answer and show there a small piece of code. You cannot understand it in a comment...

Comment: @user16316847 Edited the answer and added a second part. My previous answer was only trying to show you which is the correct way to deal with `Find`. Without some/any error handling...

Comment: Thanks for additional code. I had an issue in two points, when wanted to convert your find method code to new situatin:1)- I need to search in rows, now. That's why I changed Range(C:C) to Range(5:5)...It didnot worked out, I tried as Range(Cells(5,1),Cells(5,10000))...Also did not help.2) Then I tried to manipulate with FInd, After:=.cells(1,1)

Comment: @user16316847 It is absurd to  imagine that I can have an opinion if I do not understand what you try doing. You must study the function as Microsoft describes its parameters! For instance, did you change `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` in `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns`? Do you want finding a whole cell content, or only part of it? Without knowing how your range looks, I am afraid that I cannot help. I am not a mind reader and I learned VBA only by doing. I never used any 'resource' to learn. I experimented and search on internet when I had a problem. I even never asked anybody. I always found a solution.